# POWER BI - GROUPBY() and SUMX()

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello everyone I can't get why my measure or column (tried with both) doesn't work. I am beginner in Power BI (Advanced in TIBCO spotfire)

[image]

[image]

```
Mesure 1 = GROUPBY(VUE_TACHES;VUE_TACHES[PREF];VUE_TACHES[ACTIVITE];"group_by_gsp_activite";SUMX(CURRENTGROUP();VUE_TACHES[REEST]))
```

It's telling me that multiples colonnes can't be change in scalar value. Does someone have a clue? I looked on the internet and tried different formula but i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that you need to create a new table, instead of trying to add a column or measure.

Try this. Click on the "Modeling" tab and then on "New Table".

[image]

Then enter your code in the formula bar:

```
Table = GROUPBY(VUE_TACHES,VUE_TACHES[PREF],VUE_TACHES[ACTIVITE],"group_by_gsp_activite",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),VUE_TACHES[REEST]))
```

You should see this result:

[image]